# How to mount network (Samba/CIFS) drives to WSL2 automatically?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In setting up a NAS share to a new WSL2 installation (Ubuntu 20.04), I've found a couple ways to mount the drive that work perfectly fine:

1. in `/etc/fstab`:

   ```
   //nas-hostname/public /mnt/nas cifs user=$username,pass=$pass 0 0
   ```

   Then `sudo mount -a`
2. `sudo mount -t drvfs '//nas-hostname/public' /mnt/testnas`

I've tried [wsl.conf](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/), but it does not seem to work for network drives, only local Windows drives.

I would like to mount this drive automatically when the WSL2 comes online, reboots, or anything else. I am running a couple services which require the network drives to be present when the containers start. I am trying to identify the best way possible to do this. I am not a WSL (or Linux at all) expert, so I'm unclear whether the best route (i.e. most WSL idiomatic way) is to enable `cron` service on the machine, to set something in task scheduler, or something else.

I do have the drive mounted to the Windows host as `Z:\` as well, but I would not prefer to map it to the Linux subsystem this way, as I'd like to be easy to shift to another host wholesale.

Answer (score 1):

So the way I ended up getting this working is not great but it gets the job done. Hopefully somebody will submit a better answer later!

1. Setup my user to allow sudo access without password to the mount command (using visudo).
2. Add as the final line in my .bashrc file `mount -a` which mounts based on what I setup in /etc/fstab above.

Now all drives properly mount when the computer boots up. No further issues.

Answer (score 0):

You solved it... but zfs in your wsl or nas and zfs share a viable option I used (and a windows task). So ignore the unreferenced brief below [better answered https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/lcdxs5/zfs_in_wsl2_raw_disk_access/ and smb/cifs shares i'll find..

```
ssh root@mynas.localdomain (or... wsl --mount //?/PHYSICALDRIVEX/ --bare && wsl -d mydistro-with-zfs-wsl2-kernel..)
sudo apt install zfs-dkms zfsutils-linux samba nfs-kernel-server
sudo zpool create -o foo -O bar stank && sudo zfs create stank/DATA/usershares
Per arch-wiki or ubuntu or voidlinux wiki recommendations...
sudo rsync -haHAX /myoldfs[/] /stank/DATA/usershares
sudo zfs share
Find it in networks in file explorer
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1160680)

Answer (score -1):

Add _netdev option to the fstab entry, it tells mount to wait for the network before attempting to mount them.